# Problem with assigning and displaying the PHP data array in the vue.js variable

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I have a problem with assigning an array of data from a PHP session variable to a variable in VUE.js

This is how I assign a variable with an array of data to a variable in Vue.js:

```
permissions:['<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['permissions']) ?>'],
```

When I console.log it looks like this:

```
[
    "[{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"admin\",\"uprawnienia\":\"ACUD\"},{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"admin2\",\"uprawnienia\":\"0CUD\"}]"
]
```

And when I var_dump() $_SESSION variable:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id_grupy"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(6) "admin" ["uprawnienia"]=> string(4) "ACUD" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id_grupy"]=> string(1) "5" ["name"]=> string(9) "admin2" ["uprawnienia"]=> string(4) "0CUD" } }
```

What is expected is displaying e.g. data from the ***uprawnienia*** field, but the data array assigned to the variable behaves like a string, because when I try to:

```
console.log(this.permissions[0][0])
```

It gives me '[' only.

I apologize in advance as it is trivial and I have not noticed a solution but I am new to these things.

Comment: Remove the [0][0] from the console.log() so it looks like `console.log(this.permissions)`.  Then you can see everything and why you got the value you did.

Comment: I did it and you see what I got from this above. Can you tell me how can i get any field value?

Comment: Could you post the session variable using var_export() rather than var_dump();   var_export outputs the array just like it would be used in PHP code.

Comment: Try: `permissions: <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['permissions']) ?>,`. That should return a perfectly valid JSON array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `json_encode` in php. You convert php array into a string.

JSON is not javascript object, but a string which can be parsed into javascript object.

So on client side, you need to use `JSON.parse` to convert that string into javascript object (in your case array).

Something like below should work:

`permissions: JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['permissions']) ?>')`

Comment: Why not just do: `permissions: <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['permissions']) ?>`? It should give you the same thing, wihtout the round trip of turning it into a JS string just to parse it back into JSON. `json_encode()` returns perfectly valid JSON (which JS can read and use).

Comment: That is ugly.  Why not convert the permissions array into a JS object.  That switching between PHP and HTML mode is an unacceptable programming practice.  The JS object is saved in a PHP variable using JS syntax.   Then it just gets echoed out   Like 
`echo <<<EOT 
<script>$object</script>
EOT;`

Comment: Yes. JSON.parse worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: @M.Eriksson JS  I think I am missing something here. How does JS read JSON without parsing?

Comment: @Jashwant -Because JSON is a format that's based on JavaScript. It's even in the name: "JavaScript Object Notation". An object in JSON: `{"foo": "bar"}`. In JS: `let data = {"foo": "bar"}`. The only time you need to parse it is if you get it as a serialized string, like getting JSON in a request, or if you're putting the whole thing in quotes: ´let data = '{"foo": "bar"}'`. Then JS will just see it as a string. If you want to output the results from `json_encode()` in your JS directly (bad practice though), just skip the quotes and JS can use it straight off.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Could you please put together an example somewhere? I don't see how you can convert a php array to javascript object without encoding and decoding it as JSON.

Comment: @Jashwant - https://gist.github.com/foo-and-bar/bc768a8a30975ed7b685a1bcaae4bf75

Comment: Since PHP is server side, the result from `json_encode()` will just be echoed on to the page source before it's returned to the browser. When the browser gets the page source, it will execute the JS. The browser has no idea, or even care, if it was echoed from PHP or if it was hard coded as a JS object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick code sample I did from the a Vue quickstart CDN:

```
<?php
$mock_session_var = [
    [
        "id" => "4",
        "name" => "admin",
        "uprawnienia" => "ACUD",
    ],
    [
        "id" => "5",
        "name" => "admin2",
        "uprawnienia" => "0CUD",
    ],
];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
<script>
    const {createApp} = Vue;

    createApp({
        data()
        {
        const permissions = JSON.parse(`<?= json_encode($mock_session_var) ?>`);
            console.log(permissions[0].uprawnienia);
            return {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
            };
        }
    }).mount('#app');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This PHP code prints the following HTML/js :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
<script>
    const {createApp} = Vue;

    createApp({
        data()
        {
            const permissions = JSON.parse(`[{"id":"4","name":"admin","uprawnienia":"ACUD"},{"id":"5","name":"admin2","uprawnienia":"0CUD"}]`);
            console.log(permissions[0].uprawnienia);
            return {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
            };
        }
    }).mount('#app');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit :** I think the main reason your code isn't working is that you're printing it inside a string (which itself is inside an array). You can just print it directly, but be careful of invalid JS code when the PHP variable is `null` as it won't print anything.

Comment: Some description of why this is relevant to the users problem woudl be useful. Some reason for posting this code at least

Comment: Can you provide me with any solution of printing it directly? I can't understand.

Comment: What is it with all the `JSON.parse()`? Why not echo the response of `json_encode()` "as-is" instead of turning it into a JS string, just to parse it into JSON again?